# Subject line-Preheader update Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

it appears that if I insert an email into a journey, then update the subject line and preheader, this will NOT apply to the journey automatically - but I have to update it in the journey as well correct?

It apears I had an error with a sendout and I wanted to confirm my logic.  I know you can edit content in an email and it will automatically apply to the journey as well but I wanted to make sure!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue here, is Journey builder email activity lets you set a subject/preheader that is different than what the email is configured with

SO to update this, one the email activity is configured you have to do one of the following

- Change the email in the activity to a different email and then change it back to the original email, this will cause preheader/subject line to sync to the same as the email- then click done ( and see the saving screen)

OR

- Update the subject line and preheader in the email canvas activity - then click done (and see the sacing screen) (screenshot below)

[image]

Comment: This really sucks, I did not know this as you can make edits to an email inside the journey that will apply - I assumed it would apply to subject line and preheader as well :( 

Thanks for the confirmation

Alternatively add a "check" stating that the subject is different for both the journey and email - do you wish to proceed?